# Importing names/categories with special characters (such as ® and ©) 

Tags: magento, magmi

I have a .csv file with product names and categories that contain symbols such as this: ©.
When I use Magmi to import the .csv, Magmi consistently cuts off the symbol and everything after.
Does any one know the reason for this and how to add special symbols to names/categories?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Please post your solution as a _separate_ answer, not within your question. Posting as separate answer makes it voteable and helps to keep the "Unanswered" list more clean (avoids making other people wasting their time). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Excel does not do the proper Character Encoding you need. I used openOffice Calc (their version of Excel) then copied and pasted my data into openOffice. When you go to 'save as', save it as a .csv file, where it will then (after a series of prompt's) ask you which encoding. Pick UTF-8. Upload and be on your way!